# Using BIND as a Personal DNS Server on Windows XP

Tags: dns, bind

My ISP's DNS server is very crappy and I've been trying out various alternatives to it. I came across Treewalk ( http://ntcanuck.com/ ) and BIND, and decided to use Treewalk as it seemed easier. But it's performance hasn't been satisfactory.

Can someone please guide me on how to setup BIND on my standalaone Windows XP 3 system which connects to the internet using PPPOE?

(Note: I am aware about OpenDNS / Google / other public DNS servers but do not wish to use them).

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't an answer to your question but - personally I would recommend the PowerDNS recursive DNS server. It is alot easier to setup and use.

http://downloads.powerdns.com/releases/win32/

Comment: Thank Nathan. I'll give this a try too. 
(P.S: I'd still like a BIND guide).